# Getting DB IO issue in java code because of ASYNC_NETWORK_IO

Tags: java, sql-server, async-network-io

DB team of our application has reported ASYNC_NETWORK_IO issue along with a big but optimized query that gets executed in around 36Sec and brings around 6,44,000 rows.

The main reasons behind this might be one of these:

A.  Problem with the client application

B.  Problems with the network – (but we have Ethernet speed 1 GB)

So, might be this is a code side issue because **The session must wait for the client application to process the data received from SQL Server in order to send the signal to SQL Server that it can accept new data for processing.
This is a common scenario that may reflect bad application design, and is the most often cause of excessive ASYNC_NETWORK_IO wait type values**

and here is the how we are getting data from DB in code.

```
try {
            queue.setTickets(jdbcTemplate.query(sql, params, new QueueMapper()));
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            logger.error("get(QueueType queueType, long ticketId)", e);
        }
```

Can anyone advise me on this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may be just the way SQL Server spools results to the client. I am working on a similar issue. I am trying to determine if it is a feature of ODBC and can be configured or is it just how SQL Server works :/

Comment: Have you guys seen my StackOverflow thread on this? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/179585/high-async-network-io-when-user-locks-computer-with-excel-open - Also, the important thing isn't whether you have excessive values for this wait type.  The important thing is whether it's causing blocked sessions.